The URL http://proxy-server:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error

PS C:\Users\******\Desktop\node> npm -v
(node:3832) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://proxy-server:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

10.5.0
i tried  installing and reinstalling node many times also cleaned npm-cache but still not works?
also npm install express command dosent work
what can be done

can you provide more details about your environment?

If there is proxy or https-proxy setting, then set in global config you have to use --global in the command to remove it.
So at the end this will clean-up proxies from both local and global configs.
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy


This worked for me:
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy 
npm config --global rm proxy 
npm config --global rm https-proxy

